# Cordova maxlength is not working on input type text angular in android app?

Tags: angular, cordova, input, text

In angular web app its working fine but for the specific mobile android app it accepts more characters than set limit.

Comment: please share the HTML code, did you use `ion-input`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.